# How to get first and second largest value per user id with Presto?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

There must be a more elegant solution than the approaches I'm trying. Seems like `nth_value(x, offset)` ([from windowing docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html)) is made for this challenge, but I can't find great examples, except for this example [from Starburst](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html):

```
SELECT name,
 nth_value(name, 2) OVER (
 ORDER BY name
 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
 ) AS value
FROM region;
```

But the example doesn't include the part of my question "per user id".

For example, let's say my dataset is:

| id | date | condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2000 | Stroke |
| 1 | 01/02/2000 | Cold |
| 2 | 02/02/2000 | Stroke |
| 2 | 02/03/2000 | Asthma |
| 2 | 02/05/2000 | Heart Attack |
| 3 | 01/08/2000 | Asthma |
| 3 | 01/18/2000 | Heart Attack |
| 3 | 01/10/2000 | Stroke |
| 4 | 05/12/2000 | Asthma |
| 4 | 05/13/2000 | Cold |

And the output I'd want is:
The result I'd want is the two most recent dates for each id:

| id | date | condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/2000 | Cold |
| 1 | 01/01/2000 | Stroke |
| 2 | 02/05/2000 | Heart Attack |
| 2 | 02/03/2000 | Asthma |
| 3 | 01/18/2000 | Heart Attack |
| 3 | 01/10/2000 | Stroke |
| 4 | 05/13/2000 | Cold |
| 4 | 05/12/2000 | Asthma |

It seems like the rank() function can be used as part of the solution as well:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  rank() OVER (
      PARTITION BY id
      ORDER BY date DESC) 
      AS rnk
FROM condition
```

But this doesn't seem like the most elegant building block for the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

The function - nth_value may be used with a partition applied on the field - id and order by applied on the field - date.  However, it will still return only one value per id (2nd in the below case for each id, ordered by date).

```
nth_value(name, 2) OVER (
 PARTITION BY id
 ORDER BY date DESC
 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
 ) AS value
```

If both 1st and 2nd values for each id are required, then either the Rank or Dense Rank function would be preferable as shown below. If only values for the 1st and 2nd rows for each ID are required, then the below query using the Rank function can be defined as an inline view and only the rows with the value <= 2 can be selected. Choice between rank and dense rank may be made depending on the requirements.

```
RANK() OVER ( 
 PARTITION BY id
 ORDER BY date DESC
 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING 
 ) AS value
```